Convert CSV to XLSX and add AIP sensitivity label
I am trying to convert a csv file to xlsx and add AIP( Azure Information Protection) label to it.
somehow .csv doesn't allow to add AIP label.
'''
Set-AIPFileLabel -path C:\temp\file1.csv -LabelId ----
'''
Is there anyway i can add AIP label while converting to excel from csv.

Convert it first to a xlsx, then run 'Set-AIPFileLabel' on the xlsx
$csvFile = "C:\temp\file1.csv"

$excelFile = $csvFile -replace 'csv$', 'xlsx'
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csv)
$Workbook.SaveAs($excelFile, 51)
$excel.Quit()
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

Set-AIPFileLabel -path C:\temp\file1.csv -LabelId ---- 


Thanks for this. somehow the code get stuck at $Workbook.SaveAs($excelFile, 51) since the AIP is prompting to select the label.  I will not be able to save as excel file from script till the AIP label is set.  I want the script to label the excel file during the saving command. Appreciate your help on this.
